# java IO not serializable exception

Tags: java, javafx, serialization, filechooser

I use javafx fxml files for my view 
I am trying to serialize some objects into a file by activating a method in my controller and passing a url by file chooser and passing one of my text feilds as the window required for file chooser:

method in Controller class

```
public void saveAsFile(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        Window stage = searchByRatioTextFeild.getScene().getWindow();
        DataBase.saveToFile(stage);
    }
```

method in DataBase class:

```
 private static String fileLocation;
 private static File currentFile;

 public static void saveToFile(Window stage)
    {
        File file;
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        fc.setTitle("Save");
        fc.setInitialFileName("all data");
        file = fc.showSaveDialog(stage);
        currentFile = file;
        try {
            saveItems();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    public static void saveItems() throws IOException
    {

        //seriallise
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(currentFile);
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
        for (Item item : ItemList.items)
        {
            output.writeObject(item);
        }
        output.close();
        fo.close();
    }
```

my Itemlist includes :

```
public static ArrayList<Item> items;
```

my Item is :

```
private String ratio;
    private String classs;
    private String voltAmper;
    private String voltageLevel;
    private String ITH;

    public Item (String ratio,String classs,String voltAmper,String voltageLevel,String ITH)
    {
        this.ratio = ratio;
        this.classs = classs;
        this.voltAmper = voltAmper;
        this.voltageLevel = voltageLevel;
        this.ITH = ITH;
    }

    public String getRatio() {
        return ratio;
    }

    public void setRatio(String ratio) {
        this.ratio = ratio;
    }

    public String getClasss() {
        return classs;
    }

    public void setClasss(String classs) {
        this.classs = classs;
    }

    public String getVoltAmper() {
        return voltAmper;
    }

    public void setVoltAmper(String voltAmper) {
        this.voltAmper = voltAmper;
    }

    public String getVoltageLevel() {
        return voltageLevel;
    }

    public void setVoltageLevel(String voltageLevel) {
        this.voltageLevel = voltageLevel;
    }

    public String getITH() {
        return ITH;
    }

    public void setITH(String ITH) {
        this.ITH = ITH;
    }
```

i get no error messages but the file wont be saved as a serialized arraylist instead it stores this in the file 
:

```
¬í {sr  java.io.NotSerializableException(Vx ç†5  xr java.io.ObjectStreamExceptiondÃäk9ûß  xr java.io.IOExceptionl€sde%ð«  xr java.lang.ExceptionÐý>;Ä  xr java.lang.ThrowableÕÆ5'9w¸Ë L causet Ljava/lang/Throwable;L 
detailMessaget Ljava/lang/String;[ 
stackTracet [Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;L suppressedExceptionst Ljava/util/List;xpq ~  t 
model.Itemur [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;F*<<ý"9  xp   :sr java.lang.StackTraceElementa   Åš&6Ý… I 
lineNumberL declaringClassq ~ L fileNameq ~ L 
methodNameq ~ xp   t java.io.ObjectOutputStreamt ObjectOutputStream.javat writeObject0sq ~ 
  \q ~ q ~ t writeObjectsq ~ 
   )t model.DataBaset 
DataBase.javat  saveItemssq ~ 
   q ~ q ~ t 
saveToFilesq ~ 
   St controller.Controllert Controller.javat 
saveAsFilesq ~ 
ÿÿÿþt $sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImplt NativeMethodAccessorImpl.javat invoke0sq ~ 
   >q ~ q ~  t invokesq ~ 
   +t (sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImplt !DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.javaq ~ #sq ~ 
  òt java.lang.reflect.Methodt Method.javaq ~ #sq ~ 
   Gt sun.reflect.misc.Trampolinet MethodUtil.javaq ~ #sq ~ 
ÿÿÿÿt $sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1pq ~ #sq ~ 
   +q ~ %q ~ &q ~ #sq ~ 
  òq ~ (q ~ )q ~ #sq ~ 
  t sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtilq ~ ,q ~ #sq ~ 
  ét $javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandlert FXMLLoader.javaq ~ #sq ~ 
  yt 3javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandlerq ~ 5t handlesq ~ 
   Vt *com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandlert CompositeEventHandler.javat dispatchBubblingEventsq ~ 
   ît (com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManagert EventHandlerManager.javaq ~ <sq ~ 
   ¿q ~ >q ~ ?q ~ <sq ~ 
   :t )com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatchert BasicEventDispatcher.javat 
dispatchEventsq ~ 
   rt +com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImplt EventDispatchChainImpl.javaq ~ Dsq ~ 
   Jt com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtilt EventUtil.javat 
fireEventImplsq ~ 
   1q ~ Iq ~ Jt     fireEventsq ~ 
   Æt javafx.event.Eventt 
Event.javaq ~ Msq ~ 
  Ît javafx.scene.control.MenuItemt 
MenuItem.javat firesq ~ 
  }t Fcom.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainert ContextMenuContent.javat doSelectsq ~ 
  Nq ~ Vq ~ Wt lambda$createChildren$343sq ~ 
   Út Ccom.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecordq ~ ;t handleBubblingEventsq ~ 
   Pq ~ :q ~ ;q ~ <sq ~ 
   îq ~ >q ~ ?q ~ <sq ~ 
   ¿q ~ >q ~ ?q ~ <sq ~ 
   ;t -com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatchert CompositeEventDispatcher.javaq ~ <sq ~ 
   :q ~ Bq ~ Cq ~ Dsq ~ 
   rq ~ Fq ~ Gq ~ Dsq ~ 
   8q ~ Bq ~ Cq ~ Dsq ~ 
   rq ~ Fq ~ Gq ~ Dsq ~ 
   8q ~ Bq ~ Cq ~ Dsq ~ 
   rq ~ Fq ~ Gq ~ Dsq ~ 
   8q ~ Bq ~ Cq ~ Dsq ~ 
   rq ~ Fq ~ Gq ~ Dsq ~ 
   Jq ~ Iq ~ Jq ~ Ksq ~ 
   6q ~ Iq ~ Jq ~ Msq ~ 
   Æq ~ Oq ~ Pq ~ Msq ~ 
  ­t javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandlert 
Scene.javat processsq ~ 

q ~ pq ~ qt access$1500sq ~ 
  ât javafx.scene.Sceneq ~ qt impl_processMouseEventsq ~ 
    ¾t $javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListenerq ~ qt 
mouseEventsq ~ 
  Št Fcom.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificationt GlassViewEventHandler.javat runsq ~ 
  'q ~ |q ~ }q ~ ~sq ~ 
ÿÿÿþt java.security.AccessControllert AccessController.javat doPrivilegedsq ~ 
  °t /com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandlerq ~ }t lambda$handleMouseEvent$358sq ~ 
  …t (com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkitt QuantumToolkit.javat runWithoutRenderLocksq ~ 
  ¯q ~ …q ~ }t handleMouseEventsq ~ 
  +t com.sun.glass.ui.Viewt   View.javaq ~ Œsq ~ 
  ©q ~ Žq ~ t notifyMousesq ~ 
ÿÿÿþt #com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplicationt WinApplication.javat _runLoopsq ~ 
   ±q ~ “q ~ ”t lambda$null$152sq ~ 
  ìt java.lang.Threadt Thread.javaq ~ ~sr &java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableListü%1µìŽ L listq ~ xr ,java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollectionB €Ë^÷ L ct Ljava/util/Collection;xpsr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp    w    xq ~  x
```

what is wrong in my code, and how can i make a serialized file to load from later ?

Comment: Does your `Item` class `implements Serializable`? And never just catch and ignore exceptions; at the very least, log them with `printStackTrace()`.

Comment: @Slaw i deeply apologize for my rookie mistake : No
also i would like recommendations for exception handling from you sir 
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> i get no error messages...

That is because your are ignoring exceptions by doing..

```
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

And second you can't store Object like that, you have to first convert that object to either String or JSON String then save it as file.

NOTE: if you want to store in database then it is best practice to encode it